How to identify polygons in contact with other polygons with a shared boundary of at least 3 meters in QGIS?
As part of my Master's Thesis, I deal with the development stages of unbuilt building land. I intend to divide the units of unbuilt building land within the selected settlements into 5 levels and for each level specific criteria are set.
Unbuilt land units are land parcels divided by additional boundaries.
The problem arose with the placement of units of undeveloped building land in the 3rd development stage.
I have to find out whether an individual unit of unbuilt building land has access to the public road network. An additional criteria for determination is that the unit must be in direct contact with the public road network with a width of at least 3m.

As seen on the picture above, polygons which have red borders are representing units of unbuilt building land and the polygons with the grey border are representing the public road network. My goal is to use the right tools and written conditions to find from 2000 units of unbuilt building land the ones which are suitable to criteria which are already written above.

What have you tried so far? Also, posting a few images of your data might help us visually understand what the problem is.

I’ve already tried the Join Attributes by Location tool. With which I combined attribute values, which features were intersecting or touching each other. The result is a data layer, units of undeveloped building land with added columns of atibut values of the public road network at the polygons that have intersected or touched. From here on, I tried to calculate the width with the written condition (bounds_width($geometry)) in the field calculator, but the field calculator does not calculate the width specifically for the intersection between the tangent polygons.

Provide please the exact location of example(s) as link. What is the criteria of "building land has access to the public road network"? Maybe this is an independent 2nd question. Maybe Overpass-Turbo can be a helpful tool. You can delete paragraphs 1 and 2 of your question. These have no relevance to the answer.

The criteria for a unit of undeveloped land having access to the public road network is that the unit of undeveloped land is in direct contact with a public road with a width of at least 3 m. The data I manage is national publicly available data and was not obtained from OSM. Based on personal research, I assume that it is possible to write code that could generate data generically. Unfortunately, I have no experience writing that kind of code.

If your "contact" always means intersection, you can clip the road layer with your polygons, then calculate the area of each chunk, do join by location / ID, and use it to filter out the places where the road has a very small intersection with the land parcels. This does not give you width, but it would be a close approximation taken that the borders should more or less be parallel to the road.
I would also suggest applying a small buffer for the land parcels, as it can be seen from the picture you provide that sometimes the borders are not ideally placed, and there might be small gaps between the road and land parcels - which would probably not affect access to the road network.
